# How do I get out of a login loop?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I recently upgraded from Debian Jessie to Stretch and had a hard time getting X to start due to graphics conflicts. I sorted those out through a series of purge and reinstall commands and was excited to see the familiar login screen. Unfortunately for me, after I enter my password, the screen briefly blinks and I'm still at the login screen.

I can get into the system without problem on one of the other TTY, but I can't seem to get the desktop to come up.

Other things of note:

- I have checked the `.Xauthority` permissions/ownership and they are fine (as are the rest of the files in my home.)
- It doesn't seem to matter which desktop I choose (I have Fluxbox, Gnome, and X11 options) it always comes right back.
- The logs seem pretty clear, nothing stands out as suspect to me

Edit:
The Xorg.0.log has the following EE lines:

```
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
(EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

Edit2:
Home has 100G of free space, root has 2.4G

`.xsession-errors` is empty

Adding a new user also loops. Trying to delete that user after looping the login says the user is in use by `/lib/systemd/systemd --user`

Edit3:
I got fed up with trying to fix it and since I had already tested a clean install as working and have a separate `/home` I just reinstalled and will have to install all my packages again which is annoying but I got it up now. Bounty goes to the one I thought was most helpful, thanks.

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. According to your description I would say X crashes. I am not familiar with Debian and I don't know if you can select between wayland and Xorg, or which one you run. I would try to diagnose Xorg problems and/or graphics adapter driver.

Comment: @nobody i added the errors from the Xorg log, any ideas?

Comment: Also check `~/.xsession-errors` in your home directory (if it's huge, first delete it using another TTY, then make a GUI login attempt and look at the results), and make sure that the filesystem containing your `/home` directory is not 100% full. Also, as a test, you might try creating a new user account and seeing if the problem happens with it also. If not, it's probably something specific to your session only and the `~/.xsession-errors` might tell you what it is.

Comment: Check if `.xsession-errors` is writable by you, for example by `date >>$HOME/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: @FerencWágner Yup, I can do that without issue. I also scanned my whole home and nothing is owned by root. (Also a new user has the same loop problem so it's probably not my home specifically.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no device `/dev/dri/card0` for **D**irect **R**endering **I**nfrastructure, so there's only software renderer available, which might not fit the currently assigned driver in `xorg.conf`. Therefore, try reinstalling the drivers for X, for example (where package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` may vary):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to the ['video'](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups) group it appears to not have access to the required devices.

`video: This group can be used locally to give a set of users access to a video device (like the framebuffer, the videocard or a webcam).`

Comment: Ok I will edit to not require clarification.

Comment: @Jesse_b "This does not provide an answer to the question" How do you know that?

Comment: @mosvy: because as originally written it was a question and not an answer

Comment: @YevhenStasiv I'll check when I get home. New users have the same problem and I mesed around with the graphics drivers quite a bit so this is plausible.

Comment: Unfortunately, my user is a member of `video`

Comment: One important question not asked yet: What video card do you have?

Comment: @YevhenStasiv That is an important detail that I left out, I have confirmed that it works on a clean install of Debian10 so I don't *think* it's related to the device itself, which for clarity is a Sapphire R9 390.

Comment: Which driver packages/versions did you install? Do you know if they were the same versions as on the clean Debian 10 install? If kernel upgrades were made, were the drivers reinstalled after the upgrades?